# How to add a header component to private route component

Tags: reactjs

New to React/JS

I have a header component `<Header />` that I want to automatically be on all pages that use a private route, however I also need to use the main component and can't just put the header there. I'm not sure where to put ithe header inside of the code or if I should just create the header within the PrivateRoute component since it'll never be used outside of it.

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { useAuth } from "./AuthContext";
import Header from "./Header"

export default function PrivateRoute({ component: Component, ...rest }) {
  const { currentUser } = useAuth();
   
  
  return (
    
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) => {
        return currentUser ? (
      
          <Component {...props} />
          
        ) : (
          <Redirect to="/login" />
        );
      }}
    >
    </Route>
  );
}
```

The Header in Question

```
function Header() {
    return (
      <div className="header">
          <Link to="/settings">
        <IconButton>
          <SettingsIcon className="header__icon" fontSize="large" />
        </IconButton>
        </Link>
        <Link to="/">
        <IconButton>
          <SearchIcon className="header__icon" fontSize="large" />
        </IconButton>
        </Link>
        <Link to="/chats">
          <IconButton>
            <ChatBubbleIcon className="header__icon" fontSize="large" />
          </IconButton>
        </Link>
        <Link to="/profile">
        <IconButton>
          <PersonIcon className="header__icon" fontSize="large" />
        </IconButton>
        </Link>
      </div>
    );
}

export default Header;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a nested Route Switch for those private routes and wrapp whem the `main` and put before them your `Header` component:

```
<main>
<Header/>
 
   <Switch>
     //your private routes
   </Switch>
 
</main>
```

You can read more about the route nesting [here](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/nesting).